# Theoreme of borel cantelli application and proof

Tags: probability-theory

Let $ A_1, ... $ independent events, suppose the series of general term $P(A_i)$ diverge, let $k \in \mathbb{N^*}$
Prove that $\bigcap_{k=0}^\infty \bigcup_{p=k}^\infty A_p$ is almost sure.
Here is my idea $C_k = \bigcup_{p=k}^\infty A_p$ is a decreasing sequence thus $\bigcap_{k=0}^\infty \bigcup_{p=k}^\infty A_p = C_0$ thus $P(\bigcap_{k=0}^\infty \bigcup_{p=k}^\infty A_p) = 1$

Comment: I think you mean, show that this event occurs almost never. But I don't understand, that intersection is *not* $C_0$, why would it be? It is "$C_\infty$" in some sense.

Comment: no  i want to prove its almost surely occuring, and no $\bigcap_{k=0}^\infty \bigcup_{p=k}^\infty A_p =  \bigcup_{p=k}^\infty A_p$ @FShrike

Comment: $\bigcap_{k=0}^\infty\bigcup_{p=k}A_p$ does not equal $\bigcup_{p=k}^\infty A_p$. Why would it? Also $p=k$ is nonsense in the RHS because $k$ is undefined. Though I take back the comment about almost never, I got the two Borel lemmas mixed up

Comment: @FShrike so how do you consider approaching this problem please? why is it nonsense?

Comment: this is well known you could just google it. It's on wikipedia

Comment: Yes but why do you think what i wrote is nonsense @FShrike ?

Comment: I didn’t say nonsense. But your equality with $C_0$ is just wrong.

Comment: So what do you think the correct notation should be @FShrike ?

Comment: also why should the probability of $C_0$ be $1$? This needs justification

Comment: The papers: **1.** Chung, K.L., Erdos, P., 1952. *On the application of the Borel-Cantelli lemma.* Trans. Amer.
Math. Soc. 72, 179–186., **and**  **2.** Petrov, V. V., *A note on the Borel-Cantelli lemma.* Statist. Probab. Lett. 58 (2002), no. 3,
283–286. May help you to prove this property, as far as I know the proof is not as simple as you put it in your question.